# Change layout in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have encountered another small problem regarding a ggplot bar plot:

```
temp<-tribble(
 ~kt, ~absent, ~`absent, represented`, ~`absent, not represented`,
 "Berne", 97.5, 2.5, 0,
 "Basel", 97.1, 1, 1.9,
 "Zurich", 99.2, 0.8, 0,
 "Geneva", 93.8, 3.9, 2.3
)

temp2 <- gather(temp, ` `, val, -kt)
temp2$` `<-temp2$` ` %>% fct_relevel('absent','absent, represented', 'absent, not represented')
temp2[,2] <- as.factor(temp2[[2]])
temp2[,2] <- factor(temp2$` `, levels = rev(levels(temp2$` `)))

ggplot(temp2, aes(kt, val, fill = ` `)) +   geom_col(color='black', position='dodge') +
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x='City', y='Percentage') + scale_fill_grey(start = 0.5, end = .9)+
scale_y_continuous()+
 geom_text(aes(label=val), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), hjust=-0.3, vjust=.4, size=3)+
 guides(fill=guide_legend(title='Label', reverse=T))+
 coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100))+
 coord_flip(ylim=c(0, 100))
```

My problem is, that on the upper bar the number is cropped and I have no clue how to enlarge the space between the number and the border of the plot. I could certainly widen the scale of the axis (e.g. from 0% to 120%), but that's not what I want. Does anyone have a solution? Thank you!

Comment: `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.2,0))` might be worth a shot.

Comment: It will work if you widen the scale a little bit. Like from 0% to 105%. Otherwise, you can try a different `hjust` value, but the number will touch the bar.

Comment: I assume you don't want to expand your axis, because you don't want to see any values above 100(%). You can expand it and then add something like `breaks = c(0,25,50,75,100)` in `scale_y_continuous` in order to show only up to 100 and also have space for your numbers above the bars.

Comment: You can also try to set the `hjust` alignment as "inward", if you are willing to bring the label *inside* the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many commenters have suggested, you could expand the y-axis a bit or move the label. A completely different approach is to disable 'clipping' on the panel, as such, where `p` is the ggplot object:

```
g <- ggplotGrob(p)
> g
TableGrob (12 x 11) "layout": 19 grobs
    z         cells       name                                            grob
1   0 ( 1-12, 1-11) background               rect[plot.background..rect.32871]
2   5 ( 6- 6, 4- 4)     spacer                                  zeroGrob[NULL]
3   7 ( 7- 7, 4- 4)     axis-l           absoluteGrob[GRID.absoluteGrob.32832]
4   3 ( 8- 8, 4- 4)     spacer                                  zeroGrob[NULL]
5   6 ( 6- 6, 5- 5)     axis-t                                  zeroGrob[NULL]
6   1 ( 7- 7, 5- 5)      panel                      gTree[panel-1.gTree.32818]
7   9 ( 8- 8, 5- 5)     axis-b           absoluteGrob[GRID.absoluteGrob.32825]
8   4 ( 6- 6, 6- 6)     spacer                                  zeroGrob[NULL]
9   8 ( 7- 7, 6- 6)     axis-r                                  zeroGrob[NULL]
10  2 ( 8- 8, 6- 6)     spacer                                  zeroGrob[NULL]
11 10 ( 5- 5, 5- 5)     xlab-t                                  zeroGrob[NULL]
12 11 ( 9- 9, 5- 5)     xlab-b titleGrob[axis.title.x.bottom..titleGrob.32838]
13 12 ( 7- 7, 3- 3)     ylab-l   titleGrob[axis.title.y.left..titleGrob.32835]
14 13 ( 7- 7, 7- 7)     ylab-r                                  zeroGrob[NULL]
15 14 ( 7- 7, 9- 9)  guide-box                               gtable[guide-box]
16 15 ( 4- 4, 5- 5)   subtitle         zeroGrob[plot.subtitle..zeroGrob.32867]
17 16 ( 3- 3, 5- 5)      title            zeroGrob[plot.title..zeroGrob.32866]
18 17 (10-10, 5- 5)    caption          zeroGrob[plot.caption..zeroGrob.32869]
19 18 ( 2- 2, 2- 2)        tag              zeroGrob[plot.tag..zeroGrob.32868]
> i <- which(g$layout$name == 'panel')
> g$layout$clip[i] <- 'off'
> library(grid)
> grid.draw(g)
```

Only downside to this approach is that the the panel border is drawn *on top* of the panel and its contents.